# How can I iterate through a string and also know the index (current position)?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Often when iterating through a string (or any enumerable object), we are not only interested in the current value, but also the position (index). To accomplish this by using `string::iterator` we have to maintain a separate index:

```
string str ("Test string");
string::iterator it;
int index = 0;
for ( it = str.begin() ; it < str.end(); it++ ,index++)
{
    cout << index << *it;
}
```

The style shown above does not seem superior to the 'c-style':

```
string str ("Test string");
for ( int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    cout << i << str[i] ;
}
```

In Ruby, we can get both content and index in a elegant way:

```
"hello".split("").each_with_index {|c, i| puts "#{i} , #{c}" }
```

So, what is the best practice in C++ to iterate through an enumerable object and also keep track of the current index?

Comment: Beware in the second block of code! str.length() is of type std::string::size_type, so you need to declare the variable i with std::string::size_type otherwise compiler gives you unnecessary warning.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I've never heard of a best practice for this specific question. However, one best practice in general is to use the simplest solution that solves the problem. In this case the array-style access (or c-style if you want to call it that) is the simplest way to iterate while having the index value available. So I would certainly recommend that way.

Comment: an example would be nice :P

Comment: @NickHall He's referring to the second block of code in the OP's question as an example.

Answer (score 55):

Like this:

```
    std::string s("Test string");
    std::string::iterator it = s.begin();

    //Use the iterator...
    ++it;
    //...

    std::cout << "index is: " << std::distance(s.begin(), it) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use standard STL function distance as mentioned before

```
index = std::distance(s.begin(), it);
```

Also, you can access string and some other containers with the c-like interface:

```
for (i=0;i<string1.length();i++) string1[i];
```

Comment: btw, in my implementation indexes work much faster that iterators (5x and more)

Answer (score 13):

A good practice would be based on readability, e.g.:

```
string str ("Test string");
for (int index = 0, auto it = str.begin(); it < str.end(); ++it)
   cout << index++ << *it;
```

Or:

```
string str ("Test string");
for (int index = 0, auto it = str.begin(); it < str.end(); ++it, ++index)
   cout << index << *it;
```

Or your original:

```
string str ("Test string");
int index = 0;
for (auto it = str.begin() ; it < str.end(); ++it, ++index)
   cout << index << *it;
```

Etc. Whatever is easiest and cleanest to you.

It's not clear there is any one best practice as you'll need a counter variable somewhere. The question seems to be whether where you define it and how it is incremented works well for you.

Comment: My previous edit is correct, @Alex Reynolds. Check [It's not possible to declare two variables of different types in the initialization body of a `for` loop in `C++`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop) and [this](https://ideone.com/lngBfo).

Answer (score 3):

For strings, you can use `string.c_str()` which will return you a const char*, which can be treated as an array, example:

```
const char* strdata = str.c_str();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    cout << i << strdata[i];
```

Comment: This question is similar to my own so I would rather ask here, how do you compare the value of stardata[i] to " "? Is there a way to convert it to char?

Answer (score 3):

I would use it-str.begin()
In this particular case std::distance and operator- are the same. But if container will change to something without random access, std::distance will increment first argument until it reach second, giving thus linear time and operator- will not compile.
Personally I prefer the second behaviour - it's better to be notified when you algorithm from O(n) became O(n^2)...

Answer (score 2):

Since `std::distance` is only constant time for random-access iterators, I would probably prefer explicit iterator arithmetic. 
Also, since we're writing C++ code here, I do believe a more C++ idiomatic solution is preferable over a C-style approach.

```
string str{"Test string"};
auto begin = str.begin();

for (auto it = str.begin(), end = str.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    cout << it - begin << *it;
}
```