# For every character in string

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, character

How would I do a for loop on every character in string in C++?

Comment: What kind of string? C-string, or `std::string`?

Comment: It's read in a from a text file, so I'm assuming std::

Comment: What kind of character? `char`, Unicode code point, extended grapheme cluster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate through a string and also know the index (current position)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315041/how-can-i-iterate-through-a-string-and-also-know-the-index-current-position). Don't worry about the `index` part in the answers.

Answer (score 538, accepted):

1. Looping through the [characters](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#1) of a `std::string`, using a range-based for loop (it's from C++11, already supported in recent releases of GCC, clang, and the VC11 beta):

   ```
   std::string str = ???;
   for(char& c : str) {
       do_things_with(c);
   }
   ```
2. Looping through the characters of a `std::string` with iterators:

   ```
   std::string str = ???;
   for(std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
       do_things_with(*it);
   }
   ```
3. Looping through the characters of a `std::string` with an old-fashioned for-loop:

   ```
   std::string str = ???;
   for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
       do_things_with(str[i]);
   }
   ```
4. Looping through the characters of a null-terminated character array:

   ```
   char* str = ???;
   for(char* it = str; *it; ++it) {
       do_things_with(*it);
   }
   ```

Comment: This does confuse me somewhat, given std::string is UTF8 (assumed to be), so encoding is possibly variable length.  Are you iterating through the bytes in the string or the characters here?

Comment: `std::string` is (defined to be) a null-terminated sequence of `char` objects.

Comment: @Robinson: That's a faulty assumption. A very faulty assumption. Also, "character" has so many different meanings, it's best to strictly avoid the term.

Comment: Well, OK, it has no encoding, however given the ubiquity of utf8 now (especially on the web) and the fact that one might want a single consistent encoding throughout a pipeline or application, for the basis of this discussion my std::strings are all utf8 :p.

Comment: @Robinson: And all of mine are treated as encoding-less because I am not programming in a user-facing domain (that is, there are no strings destined to be rendered to humans). If you want to talk about character encodings, you need to talk about a higher-level abstraction _on top of_ `std::string`, which is just a series of bytes.

Comment: Is it possible to peek at the next character with your #1 example?

Comment: also, cases 2 and 3 are good example of where you can/should use "auto"

Comment: This does NOT loop over each character of the string. It loops over each byte of the representation of the string as a sequence of bytes. However, a character may consist of a sequence of multiple bytes.

Comment: @FlorianWinter in C++, "each byte of the representation of the string as a sequence of bytes" is called a character http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#1. (Yes, it sucks)

Comment: Is it possible to use `auto& c` in case 1 ?

Comment: We should speak of bytes, rather than characters, it is very hard to fit multi byte unicode into 8-N-1 say, and we may have to from time to time.

Comment: (1.) For const strings, const must be used for single char: `for(const char& c : word)`

Comment: `char&` produces unnecessary dereferencings, which involves more than a single byte of `char`. Use `const char` instead.

Comment: `clang-tidy -modernize-loop-convert` discourages you from using the old fashioned option (3) in favor of forrange option (1)

Comment: **@(past myself)** … if you’re to use the `const char`s as read-only. Writing to it needs `char` references (`char&`).

Answer (score 40):

A for loop can be implemented like this:

```
string str("HELLO");
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
    cout << str[i];
}
```

This will print the string character by character. `str[i]` returns character at index `i`.

If it is a character array:

```
char str[6] = "hello";
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
    cout << str[i];
}
```

Basically above two are two type of strings supported by c++.
The second is called c string and the first is called std string or(c++ string).I would suggest use c++ string,much Easy to handle.

Answer (score 29):

In modern C++:

```
std::string s("Hello world");

for (char & c : s)
{
    std::cout << "One character: " << c << "\n";
    c = '*';
}
```

In C++98/03:

```
for (std::string::iterator it = s.begin(), end = s.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    std::cout << "One character: " << *it << "\n";
    *it = '*';
}
```

For read-only iteration, you can use `std::string::const_iterator` in C++98, and `for (char const & c : s)` or just `for (char c : s)` in C++11.

Comment: Here's a couple options for compilers with partial C++11 support: http://pastebin.com/LBULsn76

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thanks! `auto` is always a good idea. When using it, the distinction between `begin()` and `cbegin()` becomes relevant.

Comment: what is the role of the reference in char here (`char & c`)? Is it just to allow the modification of the character value in the case it's needed?

Answer (score 17):

Here is another way of doing it, using the standard algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::string name = "some string";
   std::for_each(name.begin(), name.end(), [] (char c) {
      std::cout << c;
   });
}
```

Comment: We have the year 2018 so this should be the correct answer.

Comment: One could also use `std::all_of`, `std::any_of`, etc. according to their needs [en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Answer (score 8):

```
const char* str = "abcde";
int len = strlen(str);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    char chr = str[i];
    //do something....
}
```

Comment: (Outdated comment, that is still probably relevant for the OP:) It is not considered good form to use `strlen` in the loop condition, as it requires an O(n) operation on the string for each iteration, making the entire loop O(n^2) in the size of the string. `strlen` in the loop condition can be called for if the string changes during the loop, but should be reserved for the cases where it is actually *required*.

Comment: @MagnusHoff: Yup, [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) rears his ugly head again.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Magnus you're right, oops been using foreach in c# for the last couple of years ;)

Comment: You should however still use strlen() outside the loop in preference to testing for null in every iteration.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any examples using a range based for loop with a "c string".

```
char cs[] = "This is a c string\u0031 \x32 3";

// range based for loop does not print '\n'
for (char& c : cs) {
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

not related but int array example

```
int ia[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

for (int& i : ia) {
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int x = 0; x < yourString.size();x++){
        if (yourString[x] == 'a'){
            //Do Something
        }
        if (yourString[x] == 'b'){
            //Do Something
        }
        if (yourString[x] == 'c'){
            //Do Something
        }
        //...........
    }
```

A String is basically an array of characters, therefore you can specify the index to get the character. If you don't know the index, then you can loop through it like the above code, but when you're making a comparison, make sure you use single quotes (which specifies a character).

Other than that, the above code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

For C-string (`char []`) you should do something like this:

```
char mystring[] = "My String";
int size = strlen(mystring);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    char c = mystring[i];
}
```

For `std::string` you can use `str.size()` to get its size and iterate like the example , or could use an iterator:

```
std::string mystring = "My String";
std::string::iterator it;
for(it = mystring.begin(); it != mystring.end(); it++) {
    char c = *it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get every char in a string by using the at function of string library, like i did it like this

```
string words;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
        {
            if (words.at(i) == ' ')
            {
                spacecounter++;    // to count all the spaces in a string
                if (words.at(i + 1) == ' ')
                {
                    i += 1;
                }
```

this is just a segment of my code but the point is you can access characters by `stringname.at(index)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the size() method to get the lenght of the string and the square bracket operator to access each individual character.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string s;
   cin >> s;
   int length = s.size();
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      process(s[i]);
   }
}
```