# How many methods in c++ to read string character by character to perform desired operation on each character?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Basically i want to discover a
situation: 
A user inputs a string lets say "sarah" and it is stored in string data type now if someone wants to do a operation on each character in the name sarah, how can it be done? like first take s from string then a then r and so on. Any built in function or better strategy?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple method using :[**`std::for_each`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and a lambda function (C++11)

```
std::string str="sarah";
std::for_each( str.begin(), str.end(),
               [](char &x){

                  //Play with x
               } 
               );
```

Else, simply use a for loop

```
for(size_t i=0;i<str.size();++i)
   {
    //Play with str[i];
   }
```

OR with C++11 :-

```
   for(char& x : str) {
     //Play with x;
   }
```

Comment: let me discover a bit this new thing to me for_each on web!

Comment: to use array style approach first i will have to store character by character in the array, for this user will have to press enter after each character like s->enter then a->enter and so on right? in this situation whole string will be enter all together like sarah->enter.

Comment: @user2917063 I've simply to say **what** ?
well `std::cin>>str;` will read input from standard input full string, then you can iterate over characters . I suggest you a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232)

Comment: <pre> <code>#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(void)
    {
       string input ;
     cout << "Enter the string into array " << endl ;
     cin >> input ;
     int size = strlen(input.c_str());
     string array[size] = input ;
     for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
     {
            cout << array[i] << endl;
     } 
       system("PAUSE");
    } <\code><\br>                                                                i think its not valid please clarify.

Comment: @user2917063 You're doing it wrong See [here](http://ideone.com/kh1dqY) Also no need for `strlen` on `std::string`, just use `input.size()`

Comment: for_each returns ASCII code of char or string of ones and zeros,

Answer (score 1):

you could use this:

1. Looping through the characters of a `std::string`, using a range-based for loop (it's from C++11, already supported in recent releases of GCC, clang, and the VC11 beta):

   ```
   std::string str = "sarah";
   for(char& c : str) {
       do_things_with(c);
   }
   ```
2. Looping through the characters of a `std::string` with iterators:

   ```
   std::string str = "sarah";
   for(std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
       do_things_with(*it);
   }
   ```
3. Looping through the characters of a `std::string` with an old-fashioned for-loop:

   ```
   for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
       do_things_with(str[i]);
   }
   ```
4. Looping through the characters of a null-terminated character array:

   ```
   char* str = "sarah";
   for(char* it = str; *it; ++it) {
       do_things_with(*it);
   }
   ```

see: [For every character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438209/c-for-every-character-in-string)

Comment: Why you simply copied and pasted everything ? The link should be made as comment.

Comment: I've brought the necessary part from the answer and linked to it. I thought that's the way it works here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:

```
std::transform(begin(str), end(str), begin(str), do_things);
```

where `do_things` is a character operation. I prefer `transform` to `for_each` because, to me, it better expresses that there is a transformation happening. However, if `do_things` takes references to characters instead, then `for_each` (or a loop) might be the better option.

Here's a more fleshed out example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // for std::transform
#include <cctype> // for toupper/tolower

// Needed because toupper/tolower take and return ints, not chars.
char upper(char c) { return std::toupper(c); }
char lower(char c) { return std::tolower(c); }

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    string name;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;

    // Make the name uppercase.
    transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), upper);
    cout << "HI " << name << endl;

    // Make the name lowercase.
    transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), lower);
    cout << "hi " << name << endl;
}
```

Comment: like this?     string input ;
     cout << "Enter the string into array " << endl ;
     cin >> input ;
     int size = strlen(input.c_str());
     string array[size] = input                         then display array @POW

Comment: Just use `std::string`'s member function `size()`, instead of strlen.

Comment: yeah, can you tell me how can i put code in comments properly here at stackoverflow

Comment: Very helpful, let me try this transform function too