# C++ while loop resetting variables?

Tags: c++, loops, variables

Here is a sample program I wrote giving me the same problem.
I am trying to find where 'A', 'B', and 'C' are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
char a;
char b[256];
string str2 = "A";
string fileline1 = "ABC"
int i;
int x;
stringstream aa;

int main(){
    while ( i < 7 ){
        std::size_t found = fileline1.find(str2);
          if (found!=std::string::npos){
             cout << "first '" << str2 <<  "' found at: " << found << '\n';
             strcpy(b, str2.c_str());
               for ( int x=0; b[x] != '\0'; ++x ){
                    b[x]++;
              }}
             aa << b;
             aa >> str2;
             i++;
             }
}
```

The output is:
first 'A' found at: 0
first 'B' found at: 1
first 'B' found at: 1
...
The program never advances to C.

Comment: You might want a new `stringstream` for each iteration of the loop. (Why on earth are you using `strcpy` when you know about `string`?)

Comment: I had to change the string into a char[] for the for loop.  If you have an easier way to do this please inform me.

Comment: @user3900624 To iterate through the characters of a string, use *iterators*: [`string::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438209/c-for-every-character-in-string) will give you an idea.

Comment: And there is so much more wrong about your code... Why use `stringstream` at all? It seems like you need it to convert from char array back to string after modification. Why not simply say `str2 = b`? Also, to me it looks like `str2` is always going to be a single character string. Then you don't need the loop to modify characters; simply do `str2[0]++`. And even better, don't use a string at all for the character you're searching for; use a `char` instead. `find` has an overload for `char`.

Comment: Your for loop could just be `for (auto &c : b) ++c;`

Comment: `b[x]++` is perfectly legal if `b` is a `string `.

Comment: You'll find most things easier if you use local variables, with the smallest possible scope, rather than globals.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppiness of the code.  I wrote this fast to explain my problem better but I guess it did not do that.  Thank You @leemes and Alan Stokes for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the line

```
stringstream aa;
```

just before the line

```
         aa << b;
```

solves the problem for me.

This is perhaps caused by use of `aa` both as an input stream as well as output stream. Not sure of the details.

**Update**

Here's your program with a bit of error checking code thrown in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char a;
char b[256];
string str2 = "A";
string fileline1 = "ABC";
int i;
int x;
stringstream aa;

int main()
{
   while ( i < 7 )
   {
      std::size_t found = fileline1.find(str2);
      if (found!=std::string::npos)
      {
         cout << "first '" << str2 <<  "' found at: " << found << '\n';
         strcpy(b, str2.c_str());
         for ( int x=0; b[x] != '\0'; ++x )
         {
            b[x]++;
         }
      }

      aa << b;
      if ( !aa.good() )
      {
         cout << "The stringstream is not good.\n";
      }

      aa >> str2;
      if ( aa.eof() )
      {
         cout << "The stringstream is at eof.\n";
         aa.clear();
      }
      if ( !aa.good() )
      {
         cout << "The stringstream is not good.\n";
      }
      i++;
   }
}
```

Output

```
first 'A' found at: 0
The stringstream is at eof.
first 'B' found at: 1
The stringstream is at eof.
first 'C' found at: 2
The stringstream is at eof.
The stringstream is at eof.
The stringstream is at eof.
The stringstream is at eof.
The stringstream is at eof.
```

Without the block

```
      if ( aa.eof() )
      {
         cout << "The stringstream is at eof.\n";
         aa.clear();
      }
```

The state `aa` of was such that it wasn't doing anything with the lines:

```
      aa << b;
      aa >> str2;
```

Hence, `str2` was not being changed at all.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem with me too.