# How to perform a byte-wise XOR of a string with a hex value in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, xor

Let's say I have the string
`string str = "this is a string";`

and a hexadecimal value
`int value = 0xbb;`

How would I go about performing a byte-wise XOR of the string with the hex value in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate through the string and XOR each character:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    str[i] ^= 0xbb;
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa4227aedb2d7a07)</kbd>

or perhaps more idiomatically in C++11 and later:

```
for (char &c : str)
    c ^= 0xbb;
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15e8343adb1fa35d)</kbd>

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438209/for-every-character-in-string).

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate using `std::for_each`, and apply a lambda to do the operation.

```
std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char &x){ x ^= 0xbb; });
```

Or a functor:

```
struct { void operator()(char &x) { x ^= 0xbb; } } op;
std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), op);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do the task. For example

```
for ( char &c : str ) c ^= value;
```

or

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ )
{
    str[i] ^= value;
}
```

or

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::for_each( str.begin(), std::end(), [&]( char &c ) { c ^= value; } );
```

or

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


//...

std::transform( str.begin(), std.end(), 
                str.begin(),
                std::bind2nd( std::bit_xor<char>(), value ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional> 

int main()
{
    std::string s( "this is a string" );
    int value = 0xBB;

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    for ( char &c : s ) c ^= value;

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ )
    {
        s[i] ^= value;
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::for_each( s.begin(), s.end(), [&]( char &c ) { c ^= value; } );

    std::transform( s.begin(), s.end(),
                    s.begin(),
                    std::bind2nd( std::bit_xor<char>(), value ) );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Its output is

```
this is a string
this is a string
this is a string
```