# char not terminating while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, char, istringstream

Okay I have a while loop going on to add chars from one string to a new string and it's supposed to terminate once it reaches a certain character mainly `' '` but instead it continues endlessly. Here's a piece of the program

```
istringstream istr(str);
char token;
istr >> token;
string t;
t.push_back(token);
istr >> token;
while (token != ' ' && token != '+' && token != '-') {
    t.push_back(token);
    istr >> token;
}
```

Comment: add `istr &&` into the `while` condition, so that it detects input failure

Comment: If you want iterate on a string in cpp look this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438209/for-every-character-in-string)

Comment: If `istr` reachs end of file of there's any failure, any subsequent `>>` is a no-op and doesn't write anything. So, `token` isn't change and the `ẁhile` condition will yield the same result at every loop. That's why it continues endlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop will work infinite if `str` starts with `' '`, `'+'` or `'-'`. You will skip the first token. To avoid it you shouldn't read *two* tokens before loop:

```
...
istr>> token;
string t;         
// t.push_back(token); // what if it's ' ' or '+'
// istr>>token; // do not read second time
while(...
```

The second case is an empty `str`. You should check if it's empty and do not process it in this case.

Also if `str` doesn't contain `' '`, `'+'` or `'-'`, loop will not stop. To stop it at the end of `istr`, add case `istr` to while. When the end is reached, `istr`'ll become `false` and the loop will stop.

---

Also can do it without `istringstream`:

```
string str = ...;
string t;
for(char token: str) {
    if(token == ' ' || token == '+' || token == '-')
        break;
    t.push_back(token);
}
```

In case if you want to continue from the place where you've stopped, you can use indexes:

```
string str = ...;
string t;
int i = 0;

for(; i < str.size(); ++i) {
    if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-')
        break;
    t.push_back(str[i]);
}

// some other code

++i; // skip ' ', '+' or '-'
string t2;

for(; i < str.size(); ++i) {
    if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-')
        break;
    t.push_back(str[i]);
}
```