# Is there a simpler way to define a condition in a for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, conditional-statements

Consider an array `arr[10]` of size 10. While getting/displaying data, we use a for loop of the following common syntax

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
```

In case of a string, it is like

```
for(int i=0;strlen(arr)>i;i++)
```

But I've read somewhere that a simpler expression like `arr[i]` could just be used in the place of condition. I've tried running a code with that condition. But I get an error. So is there a similar, simple condition expression that can be used with arrays/string?

Comment: No no. Not range based for loops. Just a simpler condition.

Comment: what do you mean by simpler?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of `for(int i = 0; arr[i]; ++i)` where you iterate until you find a `false`, `nullptr` or zero element?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Yes. Will that work?? Does it belong to C or C++??

Comment: C or C++, these are two very different languages? Also you're talking about an error, so I ask: Wich error do you get? Please provide a [mcve]. This is possibly a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299866)

Comment: Show the code that gives an error.

Comment: There are some functions that will take the pointer to the first element and keep producing output from the string of characters until it reaches the terminating zero. Is that perhaps what you were thinking of? Something like `std::cout << arr;`?

Comment: @DavidBowling: this should be an answer like there are already several, except that it is wrong.  It works for litteral strings but not for strings that were filled in during runtime and can be smaller than the used array..

Comment: @stefaanv-- well, it would only work for string literals like `i < sizeof "some string" - 1`. Comment removed.

Comment: @MohamedSafeuqJ-- from the answers below, you may notice that the choice of language can affect availability and choice of solutions. C and C++ are not the same language, and you should choose only the relevant language tag, unless the goal is explicitly to compare C and C++.

Comment: Ok. Changed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for a zero-terminated c-string you can use the following

```
for(int i=0; arr[i]; i++)
```

because the loop will stop when it encounters the nul-terminator.

This does not work for arrays, only for zero-terminated strings. (It would also work for arrays terminated by something that converts to false, but this is quite rare IMO. Thanks @François Andrieux)

Comment: This can work for arrays if you know it contains a value that evaluates to `false`. It's just that null terminated strings are guaranteed to always have that property.

Comment: Yes, but in my opinion `nullptr` terminated arrays of pointers are quite rare. Ok, there is `argv` for example, but else it is quite rare.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the [for statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) documentation:

> condition may be a declaration

With the following code to demonstrate:

```
int main(){
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    for (int i = 0; int x = arr[i]; ++i){
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The loop will exit once `arr[i]` becomes `0` and gets assigned to `x` causing the whole condition to evaluate to `false`. Why that is in more details:

> a declaration of a single variable with a brace-or-equals initializer.
>   the initializer is evaluated before each iteration, and if the value
>   of the declared variable converts to false, the loop is exited.

Comment: How the hell did I never know that ._.

Comment: Nice example to show the condition, but I hope for your boss that you are not doing this in your work :)

Comment: _The above code should (probably) be of only intellectual interest._ Why? Just because it is a rather uncommon feature doesn't mean it is bad. Same question goes out to @Chiel.

Comment: Matter of opinion of course, but even simpler would be `int i = 0; int x = arr[i++];`

Comment: Does this work in C++? You can't declare a variable in the controlling expression like that in C.

Comment: @DavidBowling It  [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9mvUx0vCN3YTtEUP) in C++ but [won't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LHkd7gDSOtLbgUy5) in C, as expected.

Comment: @DavidBowling C++ allowed declaring a variable in a *condition statement*.  Since the middle part of a for loop is a *condition statement* it is allowed and the variable will be scoped to the loop body.

Comment: @NathanOliver-- thanks for the clarification; this is why I asked if it was OK in C++, instead of asserting that it is wrong (which it is in C) ;) And another example of why askers should choose the correct language tag....

Comment: @DavidBowling For sure.  They really should pick on or the other.

Comment: @muXXmit2X. I like it, but I had the same reaction as Quentin!

Answer (score 7):

Since you said simple and c++, use std::string.

```
std::string str = ???;
for(char& c : str) {
    do_things_with(c);
}
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438209/for-every-character-in-string) post.

Comment: I presume that's a range based loop.

Comment: Yes, that is a  range based loop. And?

Comment: I wasn't looking for that one. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: @schorsch312 it's available on only the later compilers, I presume that was his issue with it

Comment: @ifma This can be a possible explanation. Nevertheless, all mayor compliers are c++11 conform.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something likes this:

```
int main() {
  char arr[] = "Hello";

  for (int i = 0; char c = arr[i]; i++)
  {
    putc(c, stdout);
  }
}
```

The output will be

```
Hello
```

`c = arr[i]` will be 0 when yolu come to the end of the string, ans thus the loop will be terminated.

BTW: `for(int i = 0; strlen(arr) > i; i++)` is correct but inefficient. I let you find out why as an exercise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler see Rons answer, you can in C++. And since the OP has finally decided to use C++, this answer is totally valid ;-)

Comment: @muXXmit2X-- do note, though, that both this answer and Jonathan Leffler's  comment were posted before OP removed the C tag

Comment: @muXXmit2X: Since the C tag was removed, I'll remove my comment.  That it is valid C++ is intriguing; it's a sufficiently recent change that I'd not noticed it fully.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is `simplier` but it is a bit different and works well for strings, not for other generic types;

You can use array[] to check for the string terminator

```
char array[10] = "hello";
for (int i = 0; array[i] != 0; i++) 
     myFunction(array[i]);
```

for string you can use pointer arithmetic instead

```
for (char *aPtr = array; *aPtr != 0; aPtr++)
    myFynction(*aPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that writing this:

```
for(int i=0; arr[i]; i++)
```

will save a few microseconds over writing this:

```
int array_length = strlen (arr);
for(int i=0; i < array_length; i++)
```

I'm also aware that constructions like the first are pretty idiomatic in C, and experienced C programmers are used to seeing them.

However, in my view, the circumstances have to be very particular for saving a few cycles to be more important than writing code that other folks will understand easily. As a person who spends a significant part of his working day looking for defects in other people's code, I really appreciate expressive coding practices.

Comment: `arr[i]` is only a valid condition if you are dealing with a null terminated sequence.  If you're not you'll run of the back of the data.

Answer (score -1):

you have many options but calling the `strlen` is the most ineffective one (especially if you do it the way shown). arr has to be the pointer to be incremented

```
while(*arr)
{
   /* do something */
   arr++;
}

while(arr[i])
{
   /* do something */
   i++;
}

do
{
   /* do something */
}while(*++arr);

do
{
   /* do something */
}while(arr[++i]);



for(;*arr;arr++) 
{
   /* do something */
}

do  // is you need to do somethingh with the trailing zero
{
   /* do something */
}while(*arr++);

do // is you need to do somethingh with the trailing zero
{
   /* do something */
}while(arr[i++]);
```

etc etc.

Comment: calling the `strlen` is the most __ineffective__ one

Comment: @Michael Walz |of course. good point.  My tablet dictionary has right opposite opinion :D

Comment: I know it's inefficient, but why would it be ineffective? It does what is says on the tin, just not in the fastest possible way.

Comment: If `arr` is an array then you cannot increment it like you are doing

Comment: @stefaanv:  The `strlen` counts every character (each iteration) to determine the length of a character array.  If the length doesn't change, the size only needs to be calculated once (preferable before the loop).  Thus the efficiency issue:  calculating a constant length each time in the loop.  *Note: smarter compiles with optimization set high may apply optimization and store the length in a temporary variable or register.*

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: kindly look up the difference between effective and efficient to understand my comment.