# Splitting a string into an array of characters using a variable for the string

Tags: c++, parsing, split

I'm trying to split a string into an array of individual characters. However, I would like the string to be input by the user, for which I need to define the string using a variable.

My question is, why does this work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
char arr [] = {"Giraffe"};
cout << arr[0];
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
string word;
word = "Giraffe";
char arr [] = {word};
cout << arr[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Because a `std::string` does not have an automatic conversion to a plain `char` array. That's how C++ works (or doesn't work, depending on one's frame of reference). Not even mentioning that variable-length arrays are not standard C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438209/for-every-character-in-string

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't work because you're trying to put a `std::string` into an array of `char`. The compiler will complain here because `std::string` has no type conversion to `char`.

Since you're just trying to print the first character of the string, just use the array accessor overload of `std::string`, [`std::string::operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/)  instead:

```
std::string word;
word = "Giraffe";
std::cout << word[0] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, the type of word is a `std::string` and there are no default type conversions from `std::string` to the type `char`.

On the other hand, the first example works because it can be interpreted as an array of `char` (but actually its just c-style `const char *`).

If, for some reason, you would want to convert `std::string` into the c-style `char` array, you might want to try something like this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main(void) 
{
    std::string word;
    word = "Giraffe";
    char* arr = new char[word.length() + 1];     // accounting for the null-terminating character
    strcpy(arr, word.data());
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
    delete[] arr;                                // deallocating our heap memory
    return 0;
}
```