# While Loop in For Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to count the cats and dogs in a string. So,

#### for example:

if the string is "cc+dd-cd",:

I want to count `2 positive cats`, `2 positive dogs`, `1 negative cat`, `1 negative dog` (yes I know this is a weird way to count, but it's part of my assignment).

I thought about doing a for loop where I iterated over the string, then nested inside the for loop, I'd have a while loop that would run until a '-', then run until a '+' or the end. I started the code, and without even getting that far into it, it created an infinite loop.

#### Question: How can I fix it?

Thanks!

```
string animalparkString = "cc+dd-cd" 
for (int k = 0; k != animalparkString.size(); k++)
   {
       while (k != '-'){
           pdc = pdc + 1; //positive dog count
           pcc = pcc + 1; //positive cat count
       }
       while (k != '+') {
           ndc = ndc + 1;
           ncc = ncc + 1;
       }
       
   }
```

Comment: Those `while` loops don't do anything with `k`, so if the condition is `true` the first time, it will always be `true`. Besides, the condition doesn't make much sense anyway, instead of checking chars againt `k`, you should check them against `animalparkString[k]`.

Comment: For starters, `k` is an index, so to compare with `'-'` or `'+'` you should be using `animalparkString[k]`.

Comment: don't forget to check K in the will loop as well, the answer by @Blaze is correct and add checks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate issue is that the `while` loops check `k`'s value, but don't modify it. So once you entered one of them you'll be stuck there infinitely as `k` doesn't change inside the loop's body.

I wouldn't bother with nested loops - I'd just go over the entire string in one loop, and evaluate each character in its turn. A neat way to accomplish this is to keep a state of whether you're adding or subtracting (according to whether you last encountered a `+` or a `-` sign:

```cpp
bool positive = true;
string animalparkString = "cc+dd-cd";
for (int k = 0; k < animalparkString.size(); k++) {
     char ch = animalparkString[k];

     switch (ch) {
         case '+':
             positive = true;
             break;
         case '-':
             positive = false;
             break;
         case 'c':
             if (positive) {
                 pcc++;
             } else {
                 ncc++
             }
             break;
         case 'd':
             if (positive) {
                 pdc++;
             } else {
                 ndc++
             }
             break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438209/for-every-character-in-string) describes iterating all characters is a string.

This is a simple solution using modern C++:

```
int sign = 1; 
int dogs_count = 0, cats_count = 0;  
std::string animalparkString = "-cccccc+dddd-cd"; 
for (const char& ch : animalparkString)
{
     switch (ch) {
         case '+':
             sign = 1;
             continue;
         case '-':
             sign = -1;
             continue;
         case 'c':
             cats_count += sign;
             continue;
         case 'd':
             dogs_count += sign;
             continue;
     } 
}

std::cout <<"dogs: " << dogs_count << " cats: " <<cats_count;
```

A couple of suggestions to help you get started:
 1. Use online c++ compilers to quickly test code
 2. If your code doesn't behave as expected, use step-by-step debugging in your IDE or print our variables as you go using std::cout
 3. Explicitly stating namespace is considered good practice. i.e:

```
// preferable:  
std::string myString; 
// avoid:  
using namespace std;  
string myString
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work without too many changes , you can simply replace the `while()` condition with an `if()`. Moreover, instead of checking the iterator value `k`, you should compare the kth string element `animalparkString[k]`.

Then you might start wondering if the code you wrote is actually doing what you expect. Possible questions you could try to answer is "how do I distinguish between positive or negative counts" and, then, "how do I distinguish between cats and dogs "? You will probably need to check also for `c`s and `d`s, not only for the operation sign!

```
string animalparkString = "cc+dd-cd" 
for (int k = 0; k != animalparkString.size(); k++)
   {
       if(animalparkStrink[k] != '-'){
           // Now you know, there will be a pos count. Dog or Cat?
       }
       if(animalparkString[k] != '+') {
          // Now you know, there will be a neg count. Dog or Cat?
       }

   }
```

Note that if you write `while( k != '-')`, it will always evaluate true and, therefore, you will be stuck there. If it is the first time working with `for-loops`, consider printing the iterator value, to understand when and where you are stuck.

```
string animalparkString = "cc+dd-cd" 
for (int k = 0; k != animalparkString.size(); k++)
   {

       std::cout << "for-loop iteration number: " << k << std::endl;

       if(animalparkStrink[k] != '-'){
           // Now you know, there will be a pos count. Dog or Cat?
       }
       if(animalparkString[k] != '+') {
          // Now you know, there will be a neg count. Dog or Cat?
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` and `while` together approach is unnecessarily complicated. Here's a simpler solution:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto const& str{"cc+dd-cd"};
  std::boolean auto isPositive = 1;
  std::integral auto pdc{0}, pcc{0}, ndc{0}, ncc{0};
  for (char const ch : str) {
    switch (ch) {
      case 'c': {
        pcc += isPositive;
        ncc += !isPositive;
        break;
      }
      case 'd': {
        pdc += isPositive;
        ndc += !isPositive;
        break;
      }
      case '+': {
        isPositive = true;
        break;
      }
      case '-': {
        isPositive = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  std::cout << "pcc: " << pcc << '\n'
            << "ncc: " << ncc << '\n'
            << "pdc: " << pdc << '\n'
            << "ndc: " << ndc << '\n';
}
```

[LIVE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fYfQPm)