# Most efficient way to iterate through a string letter by letter in C++?

Tags: c++

Is there a time difference in accessing each char using the [] operator vs calling string's iterator? I'm very curious about the time complexity of using the [] operator, since I couldn't find it online

[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/)

I also heard that it's better to use a range based loop like

```
void print(const std::string &s)
{
    for (char const &c: s) {
        std::cout << c << ' ';
    }
}
```

Would this perform better than using an iterator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For every character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438209/for-every-character-in-string)

Comment: Use a range-based for-loop. Range based for loops use iterators. They're just syntax sugar. It won't make any difference.

Comment: I would expect them to be equally efficient after optimization (compilers are smart these days) however the range based for loop is easier to use and certainly easier to read.

Comment: ***Is there a time difference in accessing each char using the [] operator vs calling string's iterator?*** Make a string of a few MB in length and see. Make sure you test a Release  / optimized build.

Comment: Side note: You almost never need the most efficient. Pick the simplest, profile the code to see if it is fast enough. If it isn't, try something a little more complicated. Profile it to see that it really is faster and proceed to an even more difficult method if it's still not efficient enough.

Comment: There is no efficient method.  Look at the assembly language.  All you are doing is changing the syntax of the loop.  You still have to perform the basics: 1) Access the string location; 2) process the character; 3) increment the loop variable; 4) check loop variable against limit.